# MVC3 - Pass back a model from RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a page in MVC3 with a model of "pageModel".

In this page I have:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_subPage", Model.subModel); } (Pagemodel.submodel)
```

In my controller I am doing:

```
 [Authorize]
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Results(pagemodel model, string frmAction)
 {
 }
```

The page loads fine the first time, but when I postback into the `httpPost` action, `model.submodel` is always null.

My question is, how do I return an updated model from the RenderPartial (if at all). I can get my model INTO the partial, but not back!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with partials is that they do not preserve the navigational context. This means that any input fields that you might have put inside this partial will have incorrect names and the default model binder will not be able to retrieve the values back when you POST. Your HTML will look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Prop1" value="property 1 value" />
<input type="text" name="Prop2" value="property 2 value" />
```

whereas the correct is:

```
<input type="text" name="subModel.Prop1" value="property 1 value" />
<input type="text" name="subModel.Prop2" value="property 2 value" />
```

In order to achieve this correct markup I would recommend you using editor templates.

So you replace:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_subPage", Model.subModel); }
```

with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.subModel)
```

and then you move your `_subPage.cshtml` partial into `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SubModelType.cshtml` where `SubModelType` is the type of the `subModel` property:

```
@model SubModelType
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop1)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop2)
```

Now when you look at the generated HTML the corresponding input field names should be prefixed with `subModel` and inside the POST controller action the `model.subModel` property will this time be properly initialized and populated from the values that were entered by the user in the input fields.

Comment: If I try this I get `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManagerSystem.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager` on the page. Do I not need to somehow tell the editor for what page to use? This seems like the correct way to do things though, thanks so far

Comment: @RawryLions, the editor template works by convention. It looks in the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder for a file called `SubModelType.cshtml` where `SubModelType` is the type of your `subModel` property on the main model.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense now. However, the type of submodel is "IEnumerable<AnotherModel.blah>". I have used this method before for enum. How would I overcome this, or would I have to write another Model?

Comment: @RawryLions, in this case the editor template should be called `blah.cshtml` and located in the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder. Since your `submodel` property is a collection, the editor template will automatically be rendered for each element of the collection. In this case the correct names for the input fields will include the index: `name="submodel[0].Prop1"` and so on...

Comment: Thanks, you've been great assistance. I swapped the loop through the emumerable type out of the partial view after doing this and it now works fine. :)

Comment: Anyway of doing this on MVC2? having same problem with it

Comment: @DiegoMagalhães, of course, it's exactly the same in ASP.NET MVC 2. The exact same Html.EditorFor helpers exist.

Comment: Darin, would you recomend this approach or having an action to process and generating the data for the viewmodel and presenting it with a renderaction in the view? thanks

Comment: @Patrick, I don't quite see the relation to your question with the original problem discussed here.

Comment: Because I need to submit a sub-model also, and I was wondering the better option, this one or using a Sub-model presented in a view resulting in a RenderAction to submit it.

Comment: @Darin, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to change your partialview to accept the top level model, i.e:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_subPage", Model); }
```

which would then render your properties in the partialview with the correct property names i.e. :

`<input type="text" name="subModel.MyProperty" value="somevalue" />`

It would also mean that your returned model in the `HttpPost` action will have to correct navigational relationship intact.

this is just one of those caveats related to viewmodels and hierarchies. Oh, btw, in mvc3, you don't need the verbose `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` for posts. You can simply use `[HttpPost]`

Comment: I passed in the top-level model and changed my sub-page to match, however I still get the same issue - "model.submodel" is null when I inspect/watch the controller action

Comment: and i presume the partialview is definately enclosed inside the beginform {tags}?

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform the following.

```
@Html.RenderPartial(
    "_subPage",
    Model.subModel,
    new ViewDataDictionary
    {
        TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo
        {
            HtmlFieldPrefix = "subModel"
        }
    });
```

Your partial view will remain as is, using the @model SubModel