# Model of list type return null after POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ParentModel which contains property 'Childs' (It is a list of ChildModel) and I have strong typed partial view with List of ChildModel as model. What I want to do is when button ADD is clicked, my controller will populate 'Childs' property with ChildModel but I have a problem because the model always went back to nothing after POST.

The first time I clicked the ADD button, the program Add new ChildModel to the 'Childs' property, but the 2nd time I click the ADD button, the 'Childs' property went back to nothing.

This is my code:

Model :

```
public class ParentModel
{

    private List<ChildModel> _childs;
    public List<ChildModel> Childs {
        get { return _childs; }
        set { _childs = value; }
    }

    public ParentModel()
    {
        _childs = new List<ChildModel>();
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    ParentModel model = new ParentModel();

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult Add(ParentModel model, string submit)
{
    if (submit == "addChild") {
        model.Childs.Add(new ChildModel());
    }
    else {
        //SAVE
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

PartialView:

```
@model List<KlikRX.ChildModel>

//do something with model

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="addChild">ADD</button>
```

MainView:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView", model.Childs)
```

Any help will be appreciated, sorry for bad english.

Comment: You need to show the code in the partial, and how your calling the `Add` method. Its not really clear what your trying to do. Every time your call `Add()` you initialize a new instance of `ParentModel`. When you post, your not persisting the data anywhere so nothing is saved

Comment: I found this thread, I have the exact same problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466426/mvc3-pass-back-a-model-from-renderpartial

guess I'll use editorfor instead of renderpartial

Comment: I suspect your trying to dynamically add new `ChildModel` objects to `ParentModel` objects. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) may also help if that's the case